# Sections not being numbered after converting with pandoc

Tags: sectioning, pandoc

I am relatively new to the language, so pardon me if I am missing something obvious.

I noticed that converting a file into `.tex` using `pandoc` causes sections in the document not to be numbered. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

\date{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}\label{section}

Text

\subsection{Subsection}\label{subsection}

More text

\end{document}
```

Any help in getting these numbers back would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers), you can control whether or not to number sections with the `--number-sections` (or `-N`) command line flag. So, if you want numbered sections, your build command might look like the following:

```
pandoc --number-sections --standalone your_file -o your_file.tex
```

In the tex output you would find a line like `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}`.

Answer (score 6):

That is caused by

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

Remove this, and you will get numbering down to subsections level. I have no idea how to make Pandoc not add that instruction though.